# Perl: Matching strings by numerical value or

Tags: regex, perl, matching

I have a tsv file which contains two columns (called TG and ESP) that have either a numerical value or are null. 
I want to filter through the file an only keep the rows that either have a value less than 1 or a no value. I have written the following while loop:

```
while (<FILE>) {
    my $line = $_;
    chomp $line;
    my @c = split('\t', $line);
    my $TG = $c[34];
    if ( $TG !~ /\s/ || $TG > 1 ) { next; }
    my $ESP = $c[39];
    if ( $ESP !~ /\s/ || $ESP > 1 ) { next; }
    print "$line\n";
```

For some reason, these if statements cause my program to skip every line in the file. I want the if statements to skip only those lines that have a numerical value greater than 1. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Add some print statements throughout your while loop as traces so you can see what the program is doing and why it's making certain decisions. Being able to trace a running program is one of the key skills of programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're skipping if either of those two fields does not contain a space

```
$TG !~ /\s/
```

Since there is no such thing as a "*null*" value in a tsv file, perhaps you just want to check if they're numerical before doing a comparison?

```
next if $TG =~ /\d/ && $TG > 1;
```